# How to find XPath for the input field

Tags: selenium, selenium-webdriver, xpath, robotframework

HTML:

```
<div class="v-input__control"><div class="v-input__slot"><div class="v-text-field__slot"><input id="input-357" type="text"></div></div><div class="v-text-field__details"><div
```

I tried this:

```
//*[text()='Enter Phone Number']/following-sibling::*//input
```

But got no success.

Comment: There is no “ Enter Phone Number” in your example. It is therefore not possible o understand what you want to achieve

Answer (score 1):

you are missing the tagname   `xpath = //tagname[@attribute='value']`

```
//input[@id='input-357']
```

Comment: <input id="input-357" type="text" xpath="1">   (This is the input button I'm trying to access)

Comment: its hard to tell from this little snippet whether its unique or not, but try updated answer.

Comment: @BonfaceWairera first of all, you need to make sure the input id "input-35" is unique. 
If so, then the XPath above must be valid.

Answer (score 0):

While constructing an xpath, the expression need to start with a `tag_name` e.g. *`<div>`*, *`<table>`* etc or a *`*`* and always preceded by a double frontslash i.e. `//`

---

### Solution

Effectively, your line of code will be:

```
//*[text()='Enter Phone Number']//following-sibling::input[1]
```